# Need to Merge adjacent HTML nodes based on class name using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to accomplish the following task.

Say, If I've

```
<div id='parent'>
<span class='a'>good</span><span class='a'>morning</span><span class='c'>world</span>
</div>
```

To,

```
<div id='parent'>
<span class='a'>goodmorning</span><span class='c'>world</span>
</div>
```

I want to merge the adjacent nodes which have same class names.

So far the only idea I've is to loop through each nodes and compare classes. But, I'm not whether that is the only solution.

Any idea or 'way to new approach' will be greatly helpful :)

Comment: Yes, you definitely will need to traverse all nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Similar question: [How to combine two divs that have the same class - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699202/how-to-combine-two-divs-that-have-the-same-class-jqquery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var endelement; 
    $.each($('.itemRow'), function(index, value) {
        if (index == 0)
            endelement = $(this);
        else
        {
            $.each($(this).children('.item'), function(i, v){
                endelement.append($(this));
            });
        }
    });

    $('.endProduct').append(endelement[0].outerHTML);
    console.log(endelement);
    console.log(endelement[0].outerHTML)

});
```

Of course, this only works by hardcoding the classname, to dynamically get the classNames and arrange them we'd have to use a library like LoDash or Underscore to do the processing.