# How can I merge <div class="tile"> with another <div class="tile">?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have tiles and I want to know if it's possible to merge tiles ?

[image]

On my image i have three tiles and i would like to merge them.

```html
Before:
<div class="tile"> </div>
<div class="tile" style="background:#012496">
  <a href="JavaScript:window.close()" style="color:white; font-size:70px;">BACK</a>
</div>
<div class="tile"> </div>

After

<div class="tile no-border-right" style="background:#012496">
</div>
<div class="tile no-border" style="background:#012496">
  <a href="JavaScript:window.close()" style="color:white; font-size:70px;">BACK</a>
</div>
<div class="tile no-border-left" style="background:#012496">
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand even your image description. Can you explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: I also don't understand what you talking about.

Comment: On my image i have three tiles and i would like to merge them.         <div class="tile">

                </div>
                <div class="tile" style="background:#012496">
                    <a href="JavaScript:window.close()" style="color:white; font-size:70px;">BACK</a>
                </div>


                <div class="tile">
                </div>

Comment: Please post before and after HTML if you meant merging HTML content - or do you just want to remove the border between them??

Comment: You mean https://css-tricks.com/three-sided-border/ ?

Comment: [How to combine two divs that have the same class - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699202/how-to-combine-two-divs-that-have-the-same-class-jquery) try this approach

Comment: No, I succeeded to delete borders but the written text is contained in the middle tile, that's why I don't want to delete borders but merge them.

Comment: It is not clear if you WANT the text to stay in the middle - please show before and after HTML and Image

Comment: So the code you posted now is before and after? That is not merging. That is removing the right and left border and setting the background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Is it what you meant?

```js
$(function() {
  var html = $(".tile").map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get()
  $(".tile").eq(0).html(html).css({
    "width": "300px",
    "background": "#012496"
  });
  $(".tile:gt(0)").remove();
});
```

```css
div.tile {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  text-align:center;
}

div.tile1 {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  text-align:center;
}
hr, br { clear:both }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Before<br/>

<div class="tile1"></div>
<div class="tile1" style="background:#012496">
  <a href="JavaScript:window.close()" style="color:white; font-size:20px;">BACK</a>
</div>
<div class="tile1"></div>
<br/>
<hr/>
After<br/>

<div class="tile"></div>
<div class="tile" style="background:#012496">
  <a href="JavaScript:window.close()" style="color:white; font-size:20px;">BACK</a>
</div>
<div class="tile"></div>
```